# Chef server on Azure HTTP redirect

Tags: ubuntu, azure, chef-infra, ubuntu-12.10

I've installed Chef opensource server on an Ubuntu 12.10 machine on Azure. **https**://instance-name.cloudapp.net works, but **http**://instance-name.cloudapp.net redirects me to https://instance-name.instance-name.f3.internal.cloudapp.net/, which doesn't exist.

I've tried to change the FQDN of the machine and reconfigure the Chef server, with no luck.
Any ideas of how to make HTTP redirect to the right URL?

Comment: Exact same issue here. Have you had any luck?

Comment: No, I just use the https:// url...

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting the same error when trying to upload cookbooks from the workstation to the server. Here is how I fixed it:

Don't try to change your FQDN. On my chef server, running the followng commands:

**~$ hostname**

returns:

**myservername**

while:

**~$ hostname --fqdn**

returns:

**myservername.myservername.b5.internal.clouldapp.net**

If you don't get the above, here is how to set your hostname:

**$ sudo hostname myservername**

I created "chef-server.rb" and placed it here: "/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb"

Here is my entire chef-server.rb file:

> api_fqdn 'myserver.cloudapp.net'
>
> bookshelf['vip'] = 'myserver.cloudapp.net'

Now that you have your chef-server.rb file, reconfigure Chef Server so it will load it:

> $ sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure

Uploading cookbooks should now work.